# Iterate through Neo4j graph matching on node properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have for example the following graph in Neo4j

```
(startnode)-[:BELONG_TO]-(Interface)-[:IS_CONNECTED]-(Interface)-[:BELONG_TO]-

#the line below can repeat itself 0..n times
(node)-[:BELONG_TO]-(Interface)-[:IS_CONNECTED]-(Interface)-[:BELONG_TO]-
#up to the endnode
(endnode)
```

There is an Interface properties I also need to match on. I do not want to follow all the paths, I just the one with Interface Node property I am looking for. For example Interface.VlanList CONTAINS ",23,"

I have done the following in Cypher but it applies that I already know how many iterations I am going to find which in reality is not the case.

```
match (n:StartNode {name:"device name"}) -[:BELONG_TO]- (i:Interface) -[:IS_CONNECTED]- (ii:Interface)-[:BELONG_TO]-(nn:Node) -[:BELONG_TO]- (iii:Interface) -[:IS_CONNECTED]- (iiii:Interface) -[:BELONG_TO]-(nnn:Node)
where i.VlanList CONTAINS ",841,"
AND ii.VlanList CONTAINS ",841,"
AND iii.VlanList CONTAINS ",841,"
return n, i,ii,nn,iii,iiii,nnn
```

I have been looking at the documentation but can not work out how the above could be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
// put the searchstring in a variable
WITH ',841,' AS searchstring

// look up start end endnode
MATCH (startNode: .... {...}), (endNode:  .... {...})

// look for paths of variable length
// that have your search string in all nodes, 
// except the first and the last one

WITH searchstring,startNode,endNode
MATCH path=(startnode)-[:BELONG_TO|IS_CONNECTED*]-(endnode)
WHERE ALL(i IN nodes(path)[1..-1] WHERE i.VlanList CONTAINS searchstring)
RETURN path
```

You can also look at https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-querying/path-expander/ for more ideas about how you can limit the pathfinding.

Comment: Thanks for this, the query does not seem to end. Maybe a quick note that I do not know the endNode, I am trying to follow the interface path which include a VLAN id. Also nodes are connected via interfaces. I have tried to expend [:BELONG_TO|IS_CONNECTED*] to include the interface but that does not seem to help

Answer (score 0):

This query should work for you (assuming that the relationship directions I chose are correct):

```
MATCH p = (sNode:StartNode)-[:BELONG_TO]->(i1:Interface)-[:IS_CONNECTED]->(i2:Interface)-[:BELONG_TO]->(n1)-[:BELONG_TO|IS_CONNECTED*0..]->(eNode:Node)
WHERE sNode.name = "device name" AND eNode.name = "foo" AND LENGTH(p)%3 = 0
WITH p, i1, i2, n1, eNode, RELATIONSHIPS(p) AS rels, NODES(p) AS ns
WHERE n1 = eNode OR (
  ALL(j IN RANGE(3, SIZE(rels)-3, 3) WHERE
    'BELONG_TO' = TYPE(rels[j]) = TYPE(rels[j+2]) AND
    'IS_CONNECTED' = TYPE(rels[j+1])) AND
  ALL(x IN ([i1, i2] + REDUCE(s = [], i IN RANGE(3, SIZE(ns)-2, 3) | CASE WHEN i%3 = 0 THEN s ELSE s +ns[i] END))
      WHERE x:Interface AND x.VlanList CONTAINS $substring)
  )
RETURN p
```

It checks that the returned paths have the required pattern of node labels, node property value, and relationship types. It takes advantage of the [variable length relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) syntax, using [zero as the lower bound](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/match/#zero-length-paths). Since there is no upper bound, the variable length relationship query query can take "forever" to finish (and in such a situation, you should use a reasonable upper bound).